# How to resolve "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" error for my npm package?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package, parceljs

I have a package called [`all-keyboardevent-keys`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-keyboardevent-keys) that exports an object of keyboardevent strings. This package is a dependency in another package that I created, `onkey-event-manager`, which I have included in a Gatsby site.

Whenever I start the Gatsby development server on my site, I get the following warning:

```sh
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings

warning  in ./node_modules/all-keyboardevent-keys/lib/index.js

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

In searching around, I have learned that this warning [comes from webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196), a library that I know little about.

I would love to resolve this warning in my package so other users don't have a problem. Unfortunately, most of the answers on this site and others are for end users and not package maintainers.

**What can I do, as a package author, to resolve this warning?**

Comment: Considering that your error stems from a file in `node_modules`, it seems like the warning isn't produced because of you doing something wrong. Errors of this kind might be worthy of a bug report to the maintainers of the offending library.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 You are right, but _I am_ the maintainer of the offending library. I want to know how I can fix this so others don't see the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency package in question, `all-keyboard-events`, had not been built correctly. I replaced Parcel with Babel, updated the build configurations, built again, and the error was resolved.

I thought this was an instance of Webpack being too particular; instead it was catching an error that my tests cases had missed.

Hopefully that is helpful for anyone else experiencing the same issue.